# Why is C++ preferred over C for commercial applications?

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c, templates

I program in C mostly. However, it is pretty obvious that many more commercial applications are done in C++.

As far as I can tell, C++ is a very complex language, with seemingly convoluted syntax and too many constructs. C++ also encourages the abuse of Objects where structs and functions will do. In fact, the only significant advantage I see in C++ is the use of templated generic types (though, according to the developers of Go, generics are bad for programs).

Basically, my question is, did I miss something? Or is C++ more popular purely by merit of luck or marketing?

Edit: I'm sorry that I apparently asked a loaded question; in retrospect I can see that the way I worded it appears to be complete flamebait.

What I meant was, since C++ has so many different constructs and paradigms available to it, why hasn't it been replaced by languages that do less but are better at that specific thing? For instance, both Java and C# are much better suited for OOP than C++ is, while C is much simpler for system-level programming, and something like lisp is more suited for functional programming. Why is C++ used over one or more of these other languages?

Comment: I think you're mistaken, Go's developers are considering adding generics. C++'s template system is very powerful and very complicated and much more than just generics.

Comment: @jozefg I should have phrased that better. What I meant was that they stated that generics are relatively unimportant, specifically at http://golang.org/doc/faq#generics .

Comment: When contemplating ugly constructs in C++, you should probably take a minute to consider how you would solve the problems they are intended to solve, in C. You might find the results even uglier.

Comment: @Mat: Different people are different. I thought C++ was a hideous mess before I learnt it, then I learnt it and found that in some places it wasn't as bad as I thought and in others it was worse. For "high level OOP" other languages are much cleaner (C#, Java) and for "low level non-OOP" C has less traps for the unwary (which is a scary thing given the number of "traps for the unwary" C has).

Comment: This could have been a constructive question if you'd avoided the whole "C++ is ugly and complex" bit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed. Please see my proposed edit, which removes some loaded words.

Comment: C is just as complex as C++.  The syntax is exactly the same.  How can a C programmer think C++'s syntax is complicated?  Furthermore Java and C# is as popular as C++ is.

Comment: Even with the edit, it's still a pretty loaded question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Basically, my question is, did I miss something?

I believe you did, but it has less to do with programming languages and more to do with the human tendency to denigrate the unfamiliar.  We do that.  It's natural.  Rising above it takes a willingness to endure the cognitive dissonance that comes with the comparisons to the familiar when learning something new.

You're doing two things you shouldn't:

First, you're looking at one language through the lens of another.  One of the things you'll start to understand as your horizons become broader is that programming languages are just toolboxes with variations on the same set of familiar tools.  The variations exist to solve specific problems.  Some toolboxes contain basic tools that force you to do a lot of things yourself; others give you things to make certain complex tasks easier.  My wife, who makes jewelry, has a dozen pairs of pliers that have very unusual jaws designed to solve specific problems.  To me they're just funny-looking because her problems aren't mine.

Second, you're looking at every tool that's not already in your toolbox as something ripe for abuse because it doesn't fit your concept of "how it is."  I have news for you: anyone with a lot of experience in a language can find a way to abuse any of its constructs.  C -- and don't get me wrong here, because I've written a ton of it -- is especially rife with opportunities for abuse.  Writing C is like owning a chainsaw: it's a great tool for removing unwanted limbs, but the line between use and abuse lies in whether those limbs are attached to your trees or your neighbors.  Constructs that enforce better behavior are the equivalent of adding blade guards and chain brakes to chain saws:  they were put there by the more-disciplined to keep them from having to clean up the messy results of the less-disciplined abusing their tools and hurting themselves or others.  A little light bulb will go on above your head the first time you realize you can do a complete reimplementation of a class without having to wonder if any other code is getting away with directly writing structure fields instead of calling the setter function you so thoughtfully provided.

> Or is C++ more popular purely by merit of luck or marketing?

None of the above.  C++ is in wide use for the same reason as any other popular language:  people have found it a useful tool for getting things done.

Comment: Not to detract from your answer (which has my +1), but I think C++'s merit as a useful tool wasn't the only factor. I read somewhere Stroustrup lobbied pretty hard to get key people to use C++ (even throwing hissy fits when some of his colleagues from academia criticized the language). Can't find the link now, but it was in an article/blogpost by one of his colleagues.

Comment: Aha! [It was Ken Thompson](http://gigamonkeys.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/coders-c-plus-plus/) (not from academia, my bad): _"Stroustrup campaigned for years and years and years, way beyond any sort of technical contributions he made to_ [C++], _to get it adopted and used. And he sort of ran all the standards committees with a whip and a chair. And he said “no” to no one. He put every feature in that language that ever existed. It wasn’t cleanly designed—it was just the union of everything that came along. And I think it suffered drastically from that."_

Comment: Also by Ken Thompson: _"In an interview I said exactly that, that I didn’t use_ [C++] _just because it wouldn’t stay still for two days in a row. When Stroustrup read the interview he came screaming into my room about how I was undermining him and what I said mattered and I said it was a bad language. I never said it was a bad language. On and on and on. Since then I kind of avoid that kind of stuff."_

Comment: My point with all these quotes is that there is some evidence there was _pretty strong marketing efforts_ to make C++ a success, just as the OP guessed :)

Comment: @AndresF. Tons of unused languages out there demonstrate that marketing efforts only makes the language being visible to companies/users, it don't make them use it. C++ is used because it's the only one that is both low and high level and focus on performance. Marketing is always a factor, but it work only on short term in engineering circles.

Comment: Stroustrup also said that there are two kinds of languages:  the ones people complain about and the ones nobody uses.

Comment: @Klaim, Blrfl - sure. All the marketing in the world won't make good engineers use a language that _just plain doesn't work_. So it wasn't the only factor. But the anecdotes are still there: that Stroustrup pushed hard for C++ adoption (that's a political/marketing aspect, not a technical one) and that he couldn't say "no", making C++ a hodgepodge language (that's a technical aspect, in the bad sense). And these aren't bloggers badmouthing Stroutstrup, but colleagues who are arguably better programmers than he ever was. Note I didn't include Linus' flamebait here :) So the OP was right.

Comment: @AndresF. You're just giving your own feelings on this without even knowing what C++ features really are. How would you knoe someone is "a better programmer" and how would you know if features got in C++ just because he wanted it to be used? (that's actually incredibly incorrect as Stroustrup mention regularly that he was against making the language ISO at first but he did it in the end because that's what made it usable by all kinds of industry). You're just trolling without real arguments here. Also, citations from former colleagues are all but arguments.

Comment: @Klaim No, I'm giving Ken Thompson's opinion of what C++ (not C++11!) was at the time Stroustrup was lobbying for its adoption. Note I quoted Ken Thompson saying C++ "wasn't cleanly designed" because "Stroustrup wouldn't say 'no' to anyone". How is that _my_ opinion? ;) That C++ wasn't adopted merely on technical merit is supported by the above quotes.

Comment: @Klaim Wait, I'm trolling because I said C++ was not adopted on technical merit alone? Wow. I mean, WOW. _Someone_ is sensitive...

Comment: @AndresF. Let me rephrase: none of what you cited have any meaning in the context of this question, this is why I call this trolling. Whatever these people told, your interpretation might differ from mine. Now, if you look at the answer, it don't point to C++ in particular because C++ is not the real subject of the question. And your citations don't help anything. Nor is your side comments. Take it whatever you like.

Comment: @Klaim I disagree. The OP asked if C++ was popular on technical merit or due to luck or marketing. This answer stated marketing had nothing to do with it. I quoted well-known and respected colleagues of Stroustrup who claimed C++ wasn't a particularly good language at the time, but that Stroustrup's strong lobbying and willingness to include everything and the kitchen sink helped. That's marketing 101. **Note I'm not talking about C++11 current merits**, which is not what this question was about!

Answer (score -2):

People want to use OOP. Also programmers want to learn as few new things as possible. Thus, when C++ first came out. It gained massive popularity thanks to backwards compatibility with C and because it implemented OOP, which was gaining massive popularity at the time. This popularity created so much momentum, that it maintains lots of it right until todays.

[opinion]

But todays, many better OOP languages exist and there is much less emphasis on backward C compatibility. I would reccommend looking into Java, C#, Python or Ruby for modern OOP language.

[/opinion]

Comment: Ruby should definitely be in that modern section as well.

Comment: @jozefg Well, Ruby is like different version of Python.

Comment: I'm gonna disagree as a Python programmer who's poked several times at ruby. But it's not really relevant anyways.

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, but then I would like to know why people like OOP. To be honest, combining procedures, types, and data structures into a single conglomerate seems bad to me. I'd much rather view data as a black box that I pass through functions than as an entity that operates on itself.

Comment: @jepugs I think that is for it's own question.

Comment: Okay then, accepted.

Comment: OOP is the least important feature of C++. Modern C++ code is *very far* from the OOP principles. Just read what Stepanov, the author of STL, say about OOP

Comment: @SK-logic But STL is build on top of templates, which are basically macro-generated classes.

Comment: @Euphoric, do you equate classes (a pretty low-level feature) with OOP (a comprehensive design methodology and philosophy)? In STL, Boost and alike, classes are nothing but types and modules. Nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: *Programmers want to learn as few things as possible?* Right, that's why most of them finish high school and go on to difficult programs in colleges & universities, to avoid learning things.